# From Google Site manipulate a Google Sheet (as a simpler page visit counter)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I am aware, that I should track my Google Site with Analytics, but I am (for certain reasons) not able to use.
Therefore I would like to add a VERY SIMPLE page counter for the Google Site. 
So for every page displayed, I would like to have a counter in Google Sheets (so add +1). [A plus to display the page counter]

Anyone done this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how robust this is gonna be you could give it a try

### Option 1: Storing data in Spreadsheet

It would be very simple to get a cell and sum it on on every request that you get.

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var cellCounter = sheet.getRange(1, 1);

  cellCounter.setValue(cellCounter.getValue() + 1);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>current sum is at " + cellCounter.getValue() + "</b>");

}
```

### Option 2: Storing data in script Properties

Another option is to use the [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)  to store the data "inside the script".

```
function doGet(e){
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  var key = "COUNTER";
  var counter = prop.getProperty(key);

  if(counter){
    prop.setProperty(key, parseInt(counter) + 1)  
  }else(
    prop.setProperty(key, 1)
  )

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>current sum is at " + prop.getProperty(key) + "</b>");

}
```

Although both options are not very robust, although depending on the traffic you expect it could work very well.